# Asynchronous running one method in one time

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

I have method how need running around 68 times, and this is waiting around 1.2 seconds. Can I running this method in few threads for not wait too much.
I try this code but is still too slow.
This is my part of code

```
for (byte parameter = 1; parameter < 5; parameter++)
{
    for (byte step = 0; step < xValues.Count; step++)
    {
        await AddMeasure(av, average, parameter, step, time, file);
    }
}

CreateDiagram(canGraph, points, xValues, yValues);
```

And this is my async method

```
private async Task AddMeasure(AverageValue av, Dictionary<DateTime, double> average, byte parameter, byte step, DateTime time, string file)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        av.Step = step;
        av.KindOfInfo = parameter;
        average = av.GetInformationForDiagramBetweenTwoTimes(time, file);

        Measure measure = new Measure();
        measure.Average = average.FirstOrDefault().Value;
        measure.Time = average.FirstOrDefault().Key;
        measure.Parameter = parameter;

        this.TimeValueParameter.Add(measure);
    });
}
```

I would be very greatful if you give me the link for tutorial, or examples with asynchronous programming. I'm new in asynchronous programming and try now to learn for them.

Comment: What is `TimeValueParameter`?

Comment: List of object who create

Answer (score 3):

> I'm new in asynchronous programming

There is nothing asynchronous about your code. You want to *parallalize* it by running CPU bound work on multiple threads.

I would refactor this code and use `PLINQ` to achieve what you want.

First, I would refactor `AddMeasure` to be synchronous, because all it's doing is using the [async over sync anti-pattern](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx). I would make it return a `Measure`, because you can't add to a `List<T>` in parallel from multiple threads, ***it isn't thread-safe.***

```
private Measure CalculateMeasure(AverageValue av, Dictionary<DateTime, double> average,
                                 byte parameter, byte step, DateTime time, string file)
{
    av.Step = step;
    av.KindOfInfo = parameter;
    average = av.GetInformationForDiagramBetweenTwoTimes(time, file);

    var first = average.First();

    return new Measure
    {
        Average = first.Value;
        Time = first.Key;
        Parameter = parameter;
    };
}
```

And then invoke it like this:

```
List<Measure> measures = Enumerable.Range(0, 6)
                                   .Cast<byte>()
                                   .AsParallel()
                                   .SelectMany(parameter => 
{
    var localMeasures = new List<Measure>();
    for (byte step = 0; step < xValues.Count; step++)
    {
        localMeasure.Add(CalculateMeasure(av, average, parameter, step, time, file));
    }
    return localMeasures;
}).ToList();

this.TimeValueParameter.AddRange(measures);
```

Note that when going parallel, you should measure your code and see if you it actually improves the performance of your code. Don't take it for granted, as it looks like `CalculateMeasure` isn't doing too much work.

Comment: in my case CalculateMeasure is doing a lot of thinks. And this thinks is call lot of times. And this thinks I want call this method maximum 10 times not almost 70 times, for to be waiting.

Comment: In my case for now is not working. How can call after all is measuring call method CreateDiagram(canGraph, points, xValues, yValues);, because in this method I show the result from measuring

Comment: I don't have results who need for create diagram. Just I need calculate faster and after all calculating is finished then create diagram.

Comment: @EvgeniVelikovevelikov Why not? Where are the results stored?

Comment: First calculate measuring one time and then add in TimeValueParameter. Then again calculate and add in TimeValueParameter etc... In CreateDiagram I foreach TimeValueParameter for create diagram with paramaters who have in this list and then show in definitely position. Maybe is wrong, for now I'm not sure. From when I start the application is working very slow. Maybe around 40 sec. Now is working around 1.2 sec. I want more to be faster. Thanks for the help to now

Comment: @EvgeniVelikovevelikov You can still `foreach` over `TimeValueParameter`. I really don't understand what's wrong with this code.

Comment: I have little problem and is changed and now I have another problem. One or more errors occurred. Thanks for the help Yuval Itzchakov. I need to know how is working asynchronous programming. Now I just copy paste code and just test it. But how is working, really I don't understand. Thanks for the help. Maybe the problem is around in my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Task[] task = new Task[count];
for (byte parameter = 1; parameter < 5; parameter++)
{
    for (byte step = 0; step < xValues.Count; step++)
    {
        task[index] = AddMeasure(av, average, parameter, step, time, file);
    }
}
await Task.WhenAll(task);
```

await blocks however is asynchronous, so just add continuation of tasks and await all of them below.